# How to fetch consecutive values for last 4 days in spark dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

i have a spark dataframe, with columns v_coalecse ,checkDate, flag

```
data = [
    ("v123", "2024-02-01T22:46:00Z", 'True'),
    ("v123", "2024-02-02T22:46:00Z", 'True'),
    ("v123", "2024-02-03T22:46:00Z", 'True'),
    ("v123", "2024-02-04T22:46:00Z", 'True'),
    ("v234", "2024-02-05T22:46:00Z", 'False'),
    ("v234", "2024-02-06T22:46:00Z", 'True'),
    ("v234", "2024-02-07T22:46:00Z", 'True'),
    ("v234", "2024-02-08T22:46:00Z", 'True'),
    ("v567", "2024-02-05T22:46:00Z", 'True'),
    ("v567", "2024-02-06T22:46:00Z", 'True'),
    ("v567", "2024-02-07T22:46:00Z", 'True'),
    ("v789", "2024-02-08T22:46:00Z", 'True'),
    ("v789", "2024-02-09T22:46:00Z", 'True'),
    ("v789", "2024-02-10T22:46:00Z", 'True'),
    ("v789", "2024-02-11T22:46:00Z", 'True')
    ("v999", "2024-02-08T22:46:00Z", 'True'),
    ("v999", "2024-02-09T22:46:00Z", 'True')
    ("v999", "2024-02-10T22:46:00Z", 'True'),
    ("v999", "2024-02-10T22:47:00Z", 'True')
]
```

i have to partition by v_coalecse and find if it has 4 consecutive Flag="True" from last 4 days , if yes pick those records from the partition

1.if less than 4 consecutive True from last 4 days is present then dont pick
2.If any false value is present in any last 4 days dont pick

how to get this in spark dataframe
needed output:

```
data = [
        ("v123", "2024-02-01T22:46:00Z", 'True'),
        ("v123", "2024-02-02T22:46:00Z", 'True'),
        ("v123", "2024-02-03T22:46:00Z", 'True'),
        ("v123", "2024-02-04T22:46:00Z", 'True'),
        ("v789", "2024-02-08T22:46:00Z", 'True'),
        ("v789", "2024-02-09T22:46:00Z", 'True'),
        ("v789", "2024-02-10T22:46:00Z", 'True'),
        ("v789", "2024-02-11T22:46:00Z", 'True')
        
    ]
```